# Finding every possible combination of elements in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

Suppose I have this array: **[a,b,c,d]** How would I go about finding every possible combination i.e **ab,abc,abcd.....etc.** This needs to include duplicates, so **abcd** is not the same as **dcba**
The purpose is to find all combinations and check if if can make the same combination from a different array. My initial attempt is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        String cur = values[i];

        for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (i != k) {
                cur = cur.concat(values[k]);
                System.out.println(cur);
            }

        }
    }
```

Which give the output :

```
ab
abc
abcd
ba
bac
bacd
ca
cab
cabd
da
dab
dabc
```

which is obviously not correct

This is for a programming challenge I'm doing to try and improve so any suggestions of a faster solution would be helpful

Comment: Start with -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Comment: Is it possible that the array contains the same element multiple times? If array #1 is [a, b, c] and array #2 is [b, c, d] both contain the combination [b, c] (and [c, b]) so this is that already considered a match?

Comment: https://open.kattis.com/problems/correspondence this is the full problem, and giving example input at the bottom. I have the matching implemented but the issue I'm having is finding the possible combinations for each array. All solutions I can find seem to provide answers where {a,b,c} would be the same as {c,b,a} and I specifically need those two to be considered different i.e order matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] data) {
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(4);
    chars.add('a');
    chars.add('b');
    chars.add('c');
    chars.add('d');
    System.out.println(getPermutations("", chars));

}

private static ArrayList<String> getPermutations(String currentResult, ArrayList<Character> possibleChars) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(possibleChars.size());
    for (char append: possibleChars) {
        String permutation = currentResult + append; //create a new string with an additional character
        result.add(permutation); //add the permutation to the result
        if (possibleChars.size() > 0) {
            //make a new list with the appendable characters
            ArrayList<Character> possibleCharsUpdated = (ArrayList)possibleChars.clone();
            //from that list, exclude the character we just appended
            possibleCharsUpdated.remove(new Character(append));
            //merge the result of a recursive call of this method and the result we already had
            result.addAll(getPermutations(permutation, possibleCharsUpdated));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, for example the result contains dcba but not dcab

Comment: Hmm, for me the console says "[a, ab, abc, abcd, abd, abdc, ac, acb, acbd, acd, acdb, ad, adb, adbc, adc, adcb, b, ba, bac, bacd, bad, badc, bc, bca, bcad, bcd, bcda, bd, bda, bdac, bdc, bdca, c, ca, cab, cabd, cad, cadb, cb, cba, cbad, cbd, cbda, cd, cda, cdab, cdb, cdba, d, da, dab, dabc, dac, dacb, db, dba, dbac, dbc, dbca, dc, dca, dcab, dcb, dcba]", which does contain dcab

Comment: You are right, my eyesight is poor, let me see if I can implement this in my program